# Как сгенерировать ID для сериализуемого объекта?

Tags: java, сериализация, serializable

Мне нужно проидентифицировать данные и сериализовать их.

Следующий идентификатор не подходит, потому что статические поля не сериализуются:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private static int inc = 0;
    private int id;

    public MyClass() {
        this.id = inc++;
    }
}
```

Как лучше всего идентифицировать объекты в таком случае?

Comment: А зачем вам сериализовать значение генератора? Оно же у вас одно на все объекты. А объект у вас идентифицируется полем `id`

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, после перезапуска приложения и десериализации значение генератора обнулится, и при создании объектов он снова будет идентифицировать их, начиная с нуля. Будут объекты с одинаковыми id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам значение генератора нужно хранить в другом месте. В базе или в файле (в обоих случаях предусмотреть атомарный доступ к генератору).

Или, как вариант, использовать для идентификации UUID

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private UUID id;

    public MyClass() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Как тут меня поправляют метод `randomUUID()` стандартного класса `UUID` генерирует UUID 4 версии. Т.е. случайный набор значений. И хоте вероятность совпадения двух сгенерированных значений мала, но она есть.

Чтобы получить гарантированно уникальный UUID вам нужно генерировать UUID любой другой версии (1, 2, 3, 5). Они базируются на текущем времени и уникальном идентификаторе компьютера.

К сожалению, стандартный класс их генерировать не умеет. Но можно подключить внежнюю библиотеку, которая умеет это делать. Например [JUG (java-uuid-generator)](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-uuid-generator)

Answer (score 0):

Надо делать так:

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    transient private static AtomicInteger idCounter=new AtomicInteger(0);
    private int id;

    public MyClass() {
        this.id=idCounter.addAndGet(1); //генерация при создании объекта
    }
}
```

В этом случае:

1. Гарантируется атомарность генерации идентификаторов
2. Гарантируется невмешательство генератора в сериализацию (`transient`)

В примере @AntonShchyrov генерация на основе рандома не гарантирует уникальность идентификатора

Comment: Вы [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1042712/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-id-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0/1042724#comment1778663_1042712) комментарий видели? Ему нужна персистентная уникальность